# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis Error while creating a table on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` 
Error while creating a table on oracle

here is what I did:

```
create table customers(
cust_num number(4),
company varchar2(20),
cust_rep number(3),
credit_limit number(15),
custraint cust_num_pk
primary key(cust_num));
```

whats wrong ??

Comment: You have a missing right parenthesis - just as the error message says. It doesn't show here because you have retyped your command, with its own error. What is a `custraint`?

Comment: Actually, @Mike W, that misspelling caused the "missing right parenthesis" error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing called `Custraint`. It's `Constraint`.

It should be:

```
create table customers(
  cust_num number(4),
  company varchar2(20),
  cust_rep number(3),
  credit_limit number(15),
  constraint cust_num_pk primary key(cust_num)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax, see the below statement works fine,

```
  create table customers( cust_num number(4), company varchar2(20),
  cust_rep number(3), credit_limit number(15), constraint cust_num_pk 
  primary key(cust_num));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a primary key constraint like -

```
create table customers( cust_num number(4) primary key, company varchar2(20), cust_rep number(3), credit_limit number(15));
```

This is called column-level constraint definition, while the ones in above posts are known as Table-level constraint definitions.

Both are correct.